# Running npm, segmentation fault "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" on new windows computer

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, segmentation-fault, nvm

On an entirely new Windows computer, I downloaded NVM's latest version (1.1.10) for windows

I than used nvm to install node 6.5.0 (I have to use and older version for my work).
However, whenever I try to run npm, it gives me a seg fault, as seen in the picture

I know I don't have any conflicting node/npm files because this is a brand new pc and these were the first things I installed.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWJvq.png)

Anybody have any tips?

I actually had to reset my pc to factory settings before this in case I had previous node/npm corruption, and I wanted to start clean, but it looks like I'm still encountering this seg error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.